# Child CSS style override

Tags: css

Supposed We have the Html structure like below.

```
<table class="main-tb">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td id ="mytd">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and the applied  css file is defined below.

```
.main-tb 
{
    font-size: 13px; 
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 5px 10px;

}
.main-tb th 
{
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border-color: #CCCCCC -moz-use-text-color;
    border-style: solid none;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 5px 10px;    
}

.main-tb td 
{
    border-color: #CCCCCC;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;/**/
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

We can see the `.main-tb td` style is applied to all the td elements in the table.
Now if i want to apply different style to one of the td elements named `mytd`, like removing the border-color and border-width from `.main-tb td` . So, what should i do ?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#mytd` is more specific than `.main-tb td`, so you just remove the border from `#mytd`.

```
#mytd {
    border: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't work if i force to add a class style to mytd element .servertd 
{
    border: 0 none;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}


<td id ="mytd" class="servertd ">
</td>

Comment: if you're specific, it will work. Try `.main-tb .servertd { border: none; }`

Comment: If you need help on understanding CSS a bit better, I'd recommend [reading the HTML Dog CSS tutorials](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/) - they're pretty good, and quite readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select that element with `.main-tb td #mytd` or `#mytd` (since ids are unique) and use `border: 0;` to remove the border.

Answer (score -1):

Use `!important` on the class

```
#mytd {
    border-color: #fff !important;
    OR
    border-color: transparent !important;    
}
```

Comment: +1 for !important, although setting the border color to white is not the best way to remove it.

Comment: -1 for !important. It's totally unnecessary, since it's already higher specificity than `.main-tb td`, and !important can easily mess up other styling that would otherwise not have been overwritten.